# PHP converting a foreach to multi-thread

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading

I'm trying to build a crawler using minkphp by behat.

My code would look like this:

```
$data=mysqli_fetch_array($urls);

foreach($data as $website){
     $vizitare= $mink->getSession()->visit($website);
     $verifycontext=$mink->getSession()->getPage()->getContent();
    //insert website info into db 
    }
```

at begining I thought about having multiple cronjobs with different mysql queries(for example start one php script with all odd ID websites and one with even ID websites)
-> this would mean I'd have 2 concurrent threads but I'd like to speed up the process a bit.

Any possiblity or idea in converting this foreach to multi-threading?

Thank you!

Comment: Cron jobs is definitely not the way to go here nor is threading. What you need to speed up the download is asynchronous I/O not necessarily a threaded process. You can achieve asynchronous I/O in the same thread with something like `curl_multi_exec()`, for example, which can send out multiple concurrent requests at the same time.

Comment: As for distributing the work load across multiple workers what you want is an actual job manager/queue that can handle dealing out the URLs to the workers. Think gearman/RabbitMQ.

Comment: Your cron job and threading ideas will fall flat on their face once you realize they cause way more problems than they solve.